# Create a different Parameter Pack from a Parameter Pack

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, parameters, variadic-templates

I am not sure what it really is that I am trying to do, so please excuse me if the title is not fitting.

I have a class template taking a template parameter pack. I would like the constructor to expect types depending on the types in the parameter pack, more specifically, I would like to pass each parameter pack element to another class template (taking one argument) to construct the constructor parameters.

So this is the structure I am starting out with:

```
template<class ElementType>
struct ElementPreset{
//... stores a preset for an element of ElementType
};

template<class... Elements>
class WidgetPreset{
    WidgetPreset(ElementPreset<Elements...> pPresets)
        :presets(pPresets){}

    std::tuple<ElementPreset<Elements...>> presets;
}
```

The above code is not working, but what I am trying to do is to create a new parameter pack from `Elements` where each element is a `ElementPreset<Element>` instead of `Element`.

Is there any language support for this in C++?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe

```
template <typename ... Elements>
struct WidgetPreset{
    WidgetPreset(ElementPreset<Elements> ... pPresets)
        :presets(pPresets...){}

    std::tuple<ElementPreset<Elements>...> presets;
};
```

I mean...

(1) when you create a `class`, all is `private` if you don't define it `public` or `protected`; so your `class` construct was `private`

(2) the a `ElementPreset<Elements...> pPresets` is wrong: `ElementPreset` receive only a type; you have to unpack after the type: `ElementPreset<Elements> ... pPresets`

(3) same problem with the tuple: `std::tuple<ElementPreset<Elements>...>`, not `std::tuple<ElementPreset<Elements...>>`

(4) when you initialize `preset` you have to expand the pack: `presets(pPresets...)` (or `presets{pPresets...}`), not `presets(pPresets)`

(5) remember the `;` at the end of the `struct` (or `class`)

Comment: No [it does work](https://godbolt.org/g/HWUibq), I just messed it up when I tried to compile it.

Comment: @Justin - things that happen.